# openSUSE 15: Unable to link using Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am trying to compile Fortran 90 programs and have a Makefile for that. I want to link to netCDF libraries (openSUSE 15 provided ones).

I tried to adapt an already available Makefile. These are the relevant lines in my Makefile:

```
FC = gfortran
ROOTDIR = /media/work/codes/fortran
SRCDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/src
BLDDIR = $(ROOTDIR)
EXEDIR = $(ROOTDIR)
FPROGS = ascii2nc
NC_C_DIR = /usr/lib/hpc/gnu7/openmpi3/netcdf/4.6.1
NC_FORT_DIR = /usr/lib/hpc/gnu7/openmpi3/netcdf-fortran/4.4.4
NC_FORT_INC = $(NC_FORT_DIR)/include # netCDF's netcdf.mod file
NCINC = $(NC_FORT_INC)
NC_C_LIB = $(NC_C_DIR)/lib64
NC_FORT_LIB = $(NC_FORT_DIR)/lib64
NCLIB = -L$(NC_FORT_LIB) -L$(NC_C_LIB) -lnetcdff -lnetcdf
INCLUDES = -I$(NCINC) -I$(FFTINC)
FOPTS = -Wall -O2 #-fno-range-check
FFLAGS = $(FOPTS) $(INCLUDES)
LFLAGS = $(NCLIB) $(FFTLIB)
VPATH = $(shell cat $(BLDDIR)/Filepath) # 'Filepath' is same as $(SRCDIR)

all: $(FPROGS)

DEPS = depends # Contains list of dependencies

# This writes all dependencies on 'depends'
$(BLDDIR)/$(DEPS): $(BLDDIR)/Srcfiles $(BLDDIR)/Filepath
        $(BLDDIR)/mkDepends Filepath Srcfiles > $@

# This writes all F90 files on 'Srcfiles'
$(BLDDIR)/Srcfiles: $(BLDDIR)/Filepath
        $(BLDDIR)/mkSrcfiles > $@

an_objs = ascii2nc.o shr_vars.o nc_mod.o nl_read.o shr_kind_mod.o \
          grid_gen.o endrun.o
ascii2nc: $(an_objs)
        $(FC) -o $@ $(an_objs) $(FFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .F90 .o

.F90.o:
        $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $<

include $(BLDDIR)/$(DEPS)
```

The error i am getting is:

gfortran -o ascii2nc ascii2nc.o shr_vars.o nc_mod.o nl_read.o shr_kind_mod.o grid_gen.o endrun.o -Wall -O2  -I/usr/lib/hpc/gnu7/openmpi3/netcdf-fortran/4.4.4/include  -I -L/usr/lib/hpc/gnu7/openmpi3/netcdf-fortran/4.4.4/lib64 -L/usr/lib/hpc/gnu7/openmpi3/netcdf/4.6.1/lib64 -lnetcdff -lnetcdf -lfftw3
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lnetcdff
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:128: ascii2nc] Error 1

Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Do you mind formatting the code snippets you paste? This drastically improves readability of your question. Also, try to be as concise as possible: as the error message (and your question title) indicate(s), this is a linking issue, so you don't need to post the whole makefile. Besides, have you made sure that you correctly installed the `netcdff` library?

Comment: do you have  libnetcdff.so installed in /usr/lib/hpc/gnu7/openmpi3/netcdf/4.6.1/lib64

Comment: Hi lubgr. I tried to format the code. Since i am not a Makefile expert i thought that this much info is useful, i do not know how much to remove or include. I installed netcdf and  netcdff libraries from openSUSE's repos. I think that all the packages are correctly installed.

Comment: Hi arved. libnetcdff.so is in  /usr/lib/hpc/gnu7/openmpi3/netcdf-fortran/4.4.4/lib64. I need to use netcdf-fortran for which netcdf is a prerequisite. Sonce netcdf and netcdf-fortran develop somewhat independently, their versions are different and openSUSE devs have decided to house them separately.